# Focus On Component Is Null

Tags: java, swing, focus, keylistener

I made a simple minesweeper game using java. I wanted to have the user click 
the space bar when a bomb was clicked to reset the game. I also prompt the user to choose the size of the board before the game is started. I have a 5x5 10x10 and 20x20 size board.

What I noticed when playing the game is that the 20x20 board is the only board that resets when the space bar is clicked. So the `KeyListener` only works if the component is focused. So I used the method `JFrame.getFocusOwner()` to see which component has the focus.

I ran the game three times playing each size once. When the 5x5 and 10x10 buttons were clicked and each board was shown the focus was null. When I did the same thing for the 20x20 board the focus was on the JPanel or MinesweeperGame which is why the key listener worked. Can anyone explain why the 5x5 and 10x10 boards have null focus when the code is the same for the 20x20 board.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
public class MinesweeperGame extends JPanel {
   private MinesweeperCells cells;
   private int mouseX,mouseY;
   private int mouseButton;
   private boolean isTitle=true; 
   private JButton fiveByFive;
   private JButton tenByTen;
   private JButton twentyByTwenty;
   private JButton start;
   private static JFrame frame;
   public MinesweeperGame() {
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            mouseX=event.getX();
            mouseY=event.getY();
            mouseButton=event.getButton();
            repaint();
         }
      });
      addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {           
            System.out.println(cells.getDead());
            if(event.getKeyChar()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE&&cells.getDead()) {
               cells.createCells();
               cells.isDead(false);
               repaint();
            }
         }
      });
      setFocusable(true);
      cells = new MinesweeperCells();
      showTitle();      
   }
   public Color getBackground() {
      return new Color(196,206,211);
   }
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(800,800);
   }
   public void paintComponent(Graphics window) {
      super.paintComponent(window);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)window;
      System.out.println("JPanel: "+isFocusOwner());
      out.println("5Button: "+fiveByFive.isFocusOwner());
      out.println("10Button: "+tenByTen.isFocusOwner());
      out.println("20Button: "+twentyByTwenty.isFocusOwner());
      out.println("Button: "+start.isFocusOwner());
      out.println(frame.getFocusOwner()+"\n");
      if(isTitle) {
         GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(0,0,new Color(119,125,132),800,800,Color.WHITE);
         g2d.setPaint(gradient);
         window.fillRect(0,0,800,800);
      } else {
         if(mouseButton==MouseEvent.BUTTON1) { 
            cells.isRevealed(mouseX,mouseY); 
         } else if(mouseButton==MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            cells.isFlag(mouseX,mouseY);
            mouseButton=0;
         }     
         mouseX=0;
         mouseY=0;
         cells.paintCells(window);
      }    
   }
   public void showTitle() {
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

      JLabel title = new JLabel("Minesweeper");
      title.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande",Font.PLAIN,100));
      title.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      constraints.gridx=0;
      constraints.gridy=0;
      add(title,constraints);

      start = new JButton("Start");
      constraints.gridx=0;
      constraints.gridy=2;
      add(start,constraints);

      fiveByFive = new JButton("5 x 5");
      tenByTen = new JButton("10 x 10");
      twentyByTwenty = new JButton("20 x 20");

      ActionListener buttonAction = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if(event.getSource()==start) {
               remove(title);
               remove(start);
               constraints.gridx=0;
               constraints.gridy=0;
               add(fiveByFive,constraints);
               constraints.gridx=0;
               constraints.gridy=1;
               add(tenByTen,constraints);
               constraints.gridx=0;
               constraints.gridy=2;
               add(twentyByTwenty,constraints);
            } else {
               isTitle=false;
               if(event.getSource()==fiveByFive) {
                  cells.setGridSize(5,5);
               } else if(event.getSource()==tenByTen) {
                  cells.setGridSize(10,10);
               } else if(event.getSource()==twentyByTwenty) {
                  cells.setGridSize(20,20);
               }      
               remove(fiveByFive);
               remove(tenByTen);
               remove(twentyByTwenty);
            }   
            revalidate();
            repaint();
         } 
      };
      fiveByFive.addActionListener(buttonAction);
      tenByTen.addActionListener(buttonAction);
      twentyByTwenty.addActionListener(buttonAction);
      start.addActionListener(buttonAction);
   }   
   public static void createAndShowGUI() {
      frame = new JFrame("Minesweeper");
      frame.setLocation(300,0);
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.add(new MinesweeperGame());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: `So the KeyListener only works if the component is focused.` - correct. Instead of a KeyListener you should be using `Key Bindings` to listen for KeyStrokes. Key Bindings will allow you to listen for the KeyStroke even if the component doesn't have focus. See [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thank you @camickr for the help I will switch to Key Bindings. Do you know why the component focus would be null for two of the boards and not the other.